# Extract a variable from an IPython/ Jupyter kernel to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to write an jupyter nbextension that opens a prompt for user input, however, I'd like to set the default value to be that of a variable (e.g. run_id) in the current IPython kernel, if the variable exists.

What I can't figure out is how to get the variable's value from kernel.execute(), or to determine if the result is a NameError.

```
var handler = function () {
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    var output = kernel.execute("run_id",  {silent:false});
    var rid = prompt("Please enter the run ID", output);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I recently managed to solve a similar problem by accessing the user namespace from the kernel shell as follows:

```
if (kernel.execute("run_id = get_run_id()", {silent:false})) {
    var output = kernel.shell.user_ns.get("run_id");    
}
```